# Block external CSS

Tags: css, html

I have an external CSS page being applied to all pages on my website.

How can i make an element that the CSS is not applied to

Example:
External sheet:

```
<style>
.item{
  //Some CSS
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<style>
.item{
   //Block CSS
}
</style>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Basically you can't unless your CSS is **more specific** than the external CSS being applied

Comment: Once styles are applied to an element in DOM, they can't be cancelled or removed. They can only be overridden. You can override old styles by applying new ones to make it like you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To echo Paulie_D's comment, there are a couple of things you can do (I am assuming you cannot edit the external CSS file):

1. Place another stylesheet with the styles you DO want applied after the link to the external CSS stylesheet - this way your stylesheet rules will overwrite the external stylesheet rules. Add `!important` to your desired rules as necessary.
2. For the elements that are affected by the external stylesheet, add inline rules
3. Namespace changes - change your selector names so that they are not styled by the external CSS. For example .item becomes e.g. .item-nostyle
4. Subtle html changes - a `<b>` tag can be rewritten as e.g. a `<span>` with `font-weight:bold;` or a `<span>` tag with `font-style:italic` may be possibly rewritten as `<i>` - **be careful if choosing this path.**

Comment: Should also note that `element.item` will take priority over `.item`